# Tela de boas vindas do Nginx não aparece

Tags: php, nginx

Boa tarde.

Acabei de instalar um novo servidor (Ubuntu 14.04), instalei a versão padrão (1.4.8) do Nginx e infelizmente a tela de boas vindas não aparece. Em sequência, aparece uma tela dizendo que não foi possível acessar este site. Cheguei a fazer um teste que é colocar o arquivo phpinfo.php na raiz do servidor e a mesma mensagem aparece.

Estou com dúvidas se o problema está no Nginx ou no php.

Alguém pode me ajudar por gentileza? Obrigado.

Comment: Se no seu caminho você especificar como index.php funciona?

Comment: Você já verificou se as configurações do sites-enable estão corretas? se o nginx esta rodando?

Comment: Bem-vindo! Podes [edit] e melhorar a pergunta juntando toda a informação possível e relevante para o teu problema? Se não vamos ter um forum onde vais adicionando informação à medida que alguém pergunta mais detalhes e este site não é um forum. Junta código, ficheiros de configuração, logs, etc...

Comment: Olá. As configurações do nginx estão OK. São as mesmas que estão em funcionamento em outro servidor. E como eu faço para saber se o Nginx está rodando sem que apareça a tela de boas vindas?

Comment: Eu digitei Nginx -t e ele retornou que a sintaxe está OK.

Comment: Olá André. Eu ainda não estou com o código da página. Apenas possuo na  raiz do servidor (usr/share/nginx/html) o arquivo phpinfo.php. O arquivo está com permissão 777.

Comment: Estou com este seguinte erro no log... 2016/07/25 14:35:02 [emerg] 21746#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/07/25 14:35:02 [emerg] 21746#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: Olá, descobri o problema. Meu arquivo default.conf do nginx estava com o parâmetro "listen" configurado para a porta 8080. Quando eu mudei para a porta 80, funcionou... a tela de boas vindas do nginx apareceu.